# jooQ code generation for particular tables

Tags: java, jooq

I have a database with many tables.
I want to start using jOOQ for my application.
But I don't want JOOQ to generated code for all tables but **only for small subset of tables**
How can I configure it?

Answer (score 1):

With the jOOQ generator configuration in a standalone XML file or inlined in your Maven `pom.xml` the relevant part of the configuration could look something like this:

```xml
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd">
  <generator>
    <database>
      <includes>.*</includes>
      <excludes>
           UNUSED_TABLE                # This table (unqualified name) should not be generated
         | PREFIX_.*                   # Objects with a given prefix should not be generated
         | SECRET_SCHEMA\.SECRET_TABLE # This table (qualified name) should not be generated
         | SECRET_ROUTINE              # This routine (unqualified name) ...
      </excludes>
    </database>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

For more details or examples for programmatic configuration or configuration via Gradle, refer to the manual: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-includes-excludes/.